# How to clear missed call notification from status bar

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-2.3, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am trying to clear missed call notifications from status bar programmatically but couldn't achieve this. I will appreciate any help.

edit:
Seems like SDK doesn't let me do that directly. Can you guys suggest me any workaround?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only remove a `Notification` that you raise yourself. You cannot remove a `Notification` raised by another application. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) could help you. Especially this paragraph may include what you are looking for;

To clear the status bar notification when the user selects it from the notifications window, add the `FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` flag to your Notification. You can also clear it manually with `cancel(int)`, passing it the notification ID, or clear all your notifications with `cancelAll()`.

Comment: Can, I want to clear the missed call notification generated by system/phone app. I guess this won't work for me, thanks for your reply though.

Answer (score 0):

The only "legal" but extremely ugly and usually useless way to achieve what you want is to show Call Log to user. And I mean literally show (becomes visual, gets focus). In case you want to do this, here's how:

```
public static boolean showCallLog(Context context)
{
    try
    {
        Intent showCallLog = new Intent();
        showCallLog.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        showCallLog.setType(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE);
        context.startActivity(showCallLog);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("Couldn't show call log.", e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

The reason behind this mess is the fact that apps responsible for call logging use cached values. You need to somehow notify those apps that Call Log has changed (seen means changed as well) and that it should update it. It would be nice if all such apps on all devices would receive a broadcast in order to refresh, but as far as I know, it's not the case.